# Trigger event listener once div is not clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div: `<div id="navUserDetailsNotifications">` and another div: `<div id="navNotifications">`. The initial state is that the first div is displayed (`display: flex`) and the second one is not (`display: none`). I want to attach `"navUserDetailsNotifications"` div 2 event listeners:

- When click on it, then the second one is displayed (`display: flex`).
- When click on `document` and the clicked element is not `navUserDetailsNotifications` then make `display: none` to the second div.

This is my try:

```
let navUserDetailsNotificationsOBJ = $('#navUserDetailsNotifications');
let navNotificationsOBJ = $('#navNotifications');

$(document).on('click', ':not(#navUserDetailsNotifications)', function() {
        navNotificationsOBJ.css('display', 'none');
});

navUserDetailsNotificationsOBJ.on('click', function() {
        navNotificationsOBJ.css('display', 'flex');
});
```

This is not working, why is it?

Comment: [How do I detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

Comment: did you try replacing $(document) with $(document.body)